# prepend each word resulting from pathname expansion

Tags: bash

I'd like to mimic some functionality I have in `fish` shell.

Say I have this structure:

```
❯ tree
.
└── a
    ├── 1.txt
    ├── 2.txt
    └── 3.txt
```

I want to get rid of the directory `a` and prepend `b` (more generally, I need to map path `a` to path `b`).

In `fish` I do simply:

```
❯ echo b/(basename a/*.txt)
b/1.txt b/2.txt b/3.txt
```

But same trick in `bash` only prepends the first element.

```
$echo b/$(basename a/*.txt)
b/1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

What gives? How to mimic this behavior in a nice way, optimally without loops in `bash` or `sh`?

Comment: In fish, command output returns not a single string, but _a list of lines_. In fish, prepending a string to a list applies the prefix to every list element. As you see, bash doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bash, you can create an array from the glob:

```
$ files=(a/*.txt)
$ declare -p files
declare -a files=([0]="a/1.txt" [1]="a/2.txt" [2]="a/3.txt")
```

Then use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to replace each prefix that greedily matches `*/` with `b/`:

```
$ echo "${files[@]/#*\//b\/}"
b/1.txt b/2.txt b/3.txt
```

The expansion is a case of the `${parameter/pattern/string}` expansion, where *`parameter`* is `files[@]` (apply to each array element) and pattern starts with `#` (match at beginning of expanded values of *`parameter`*). Because the elements are separated by `/`, the slash in the pattern and replacement has to be escaped.

Comment: Weird that someone downvoted this without explaining what's wrong. This is exactly the thing OP's asking for

Comment: Sadly, nowhere near being `fish`-elegant. But I guess it can't be done better. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

how about `printf` instead of echo?

```
printf "b/%s " $( basename -a a/*.txt )
```

Comment: Breaks on filenames with spaces and glob characters, unlike my gibberish ;)

Comment: @BenjaminW. You forgot about hitting command length limit. Still less problems than with gibberish.

Comment: This might hit the command length limit as well if there are too many files. What's your point?

Comment: Actually `echo` was just an example, I need to pass it as a parameter to command, e.g. `./binary b/(basename a/*.txt)`.

Comment: @LeśnyRumcajs Then you can utilize `find` + `xargs` combination. Pumping null-separated list of strings into xargs seems to be a common approach to building fancy arguments lists inplace. `find . - path "./a/*.txt" -printf "./b/%f\0" | xargs -0 ./binary`

Comment: @user7860670 Thanks, I already considered this approach. Unfortunately it's not good for me because it's not cross-platform (cross, being classic Linux and MacOS with lack of `-printf` in `find`).